# Equivalent of Ruby IO in PHP

Tags: php, ruby, ipc, preforking

I am searching for a way to do things like `IO.select`, `IO.pipe` in PHP. Googling for hours hasn't given any good results. Basically I need pair of file descriptors for IPC between master process and child for preform server model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do IPC communication between processes the `stream_socket_pair` is key function here